# What was it that Rosamund Pike (Amy) spits in the glass?

Tags: gone-girl

I noticed a weird thing in the *Gone Girl* film. Amy is shown spitting (saliva) in another girl's (the name is Greta, if I remember correctly) drinking glass when she was in a different home, spending some time disguising herself. What was it and was there some purpose of it?

The scene happens at around 1 hour 25 mins 37 seconds on Prime Video.

EDIT:

Here's a photo I took using my phone:
[image]

Comment: Can you give more details? or a clip of the scene?

Comment: @A.bakker I can't take screenshot of the movie on Prime Video. But the scene happens at around 1 hour 25 mins 37 seconds.

Comment: Can you identify the other character?  Who's home is this, the pregnant neighbor?

Comment: @iandotkelly I've added a screenshot. Added name too.

Comment: Ah... its the girl from the motel that Amy stays at when pretending to be dead.  She's disguising herself because she's pretending to be murdered.  I don't recall why she spits in the glass, other than she's a sociopath.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What was it..

It is nothing but her saliva.

The purpose is to get revenge. Earlier Greta had called Amy a rich spoiled girl (most probably), with which she disagreed. But she could not confront Greta as she was in disguise. So when she had the moment she spat in her glass.

It was her own way of taking revenge on Greta. She did it so that she can have the pleasure of watching Greta drink her saliva.

Also..as iandotkelly points out, she is a sociopath. She did not have anything against men in particular. It could be anyone who offended her. To prove this, the author Gillian Flynn added this thing as she says [here](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/One-Moment-Gone-Girl-Book-David-Fincher-Called-BS-67551.html):

> .....Flynn confesses, "She was in the first draft, because I liked to show that Amy’s skillset wasn’t just aimed at men, which is why I have her spit in Greta’s drink (in the movie). She’s someone who upon a slight is going to take care of it."

Comment: lol. That was the only comedy in the movie then 

Comment: I remember when entertainment was people who were paragons to look up to: Jimmy Stewart, Captain Picard.  Now, entertainment is people who are much more messed up than we are: Heisenberg, Michael Burnham, etc.

Comment: Ah yes, and Macbeth encourages violence in the youth of today, while King Lear is a terrible role model